# find intersection of two linked list with duplicates

Tags: optimization, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Say I have two linked lists
 6->14->45->38->52->18->90->null  and 
 78->38->44->6->85->52

Here the second linked list is joining with first at node 52, and also elements 38 and 6 are present in both the list. Whats the best way to get intersection point of these two linked lists here node with element 52.

Comment: You can add address of each node in a Set and check if an address is already present or not, If any address is already in Set then it means there is an intersection at that address,

Answer (score 1):

One straightforward/efficient method to find the intersection of two linked lists, `l1` and `l2`, is hashing. Here is a method you can use:

1. Make an empty hash table `h`, where the key is a nodes' address, and the value is a binary/Boolean value indicating if the node is present in `h`.
2. Go through `l1` and insert all the nodes' addresses into `h`.
3. Go through `l2`. For every node, check if it is present in `h`. If we find a node in `h`, then this node is intersecting with `l1` and `l2`.

This algorithm has `O(m + n)` time complexity and `O(m)` extra auxiliary space for `h`, where `m` is the size of `l1`,  and `n` is the size of `l2`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but can we rely on address , say I am working on java 
1. Is the solution portable across JVMs or different versions
2. Objects can move because of GC at any time

Comment: That doesn't have O(1) space. `h` requires O(n) extra space.

Comment: @JimMischel Thanks for spotting that, updated the answer.

Comment: Actually, I was mistaken. The extra space required for `h` is the length of `l1`. So in your terminology, the extra space is `O(m)`.